# Event time window in Flink does not trigger

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

When I use flink event time window, the window just doesn't trigger. How can I solve the problem, and are there any ways to debug?

Answer (score 7):

As you are using the event time window, it is probably a watermark problem. The window only output when watermarks make a progress. There are some reasons why the event time has not been advanced:

1. There are no data from the source
2. One of the source parallelisms doesn't have data
3. The time field extracted from the record should be millisecond instead of second.
4. Data should cover a longer time span than the window size to advance the event time.

The window will output if we change event time to processing time. Furthermore, we can monitor event time by checking the watermarks in the web dashboard[1] or print-debug it with a ProcessFunction which can lookup the current watermark.

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/monitoring/debugging_event_time.html#monitoring-current-event-time

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify what you mean by #2 ("One of the source parallelisms doesn't have data) above? Is this a Flink bug? If it's expected behavior, I don't see it documented anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: @karthitect hi, it's not a Flink bug. Some descriptions here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_time.html#idling-sources

Comment: thanks. So please correct me if I'm mistaken - this wouldn't be an issue if we're using an assigner derived from AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks?

Comment: In my case the problem was that I had chosen the `WatermarkStrategy.noWaterMarks()` when defining the source datastream.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you're setting `environment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)`.